# Using "For...Next" with non continuous figures

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop

I've certainly a dumb question but don't find the answer.

Is there a way of using "For i=... To..." with non continuous figures.

Let me explain : 
For example I've this lines of code :

```
GridView1.Columns(26).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
GridView1.Columns(27).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
GridView1.Columns(28).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
GridView1.Columns(34).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
GridView1.Columns(35).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
GridView1.Columns(41).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
GridView1.Columns(42).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
'And so on...
```

Is there a way of writing `From i=26 To 42 In {26,27,28,34,35,41,42}`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array or List of integers with contents `{26, 27, 28, 34, 35, 41, 42}` and then iterate through that array using the [**For Each...Next**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5ebk1751.aspx) statement.

You may, for example, adapt this example, which appears in the linked MSDN article. It is about a list of String, but you can do the same with integers.

```
' Create a list of strings by using a 
' collection initializer.     
Dim lst As New List(Of String) _
    From {"abc", "def", "ghi"}

' Iterate through the list. 
For Each item As String In lst
    Debug.Write(item & " ")
Next
```

Comment: Ok sorry...
Stupid question now that you say it, it seems logic.

Comment: @Rave It's ok. You just needed one extra abstraction layer.

Comment: Hardcoding column numbers is marginal... I think you could adapt this answer to use column names instead of numbers.

Comment: Not in my case because they can change